# Windows 10 Mirrored Drives show up as Foreign after taking them back from offline

Tags: windows-10, raid

I have a set of drives that I used in mirrored setting.
I took them offline, and after my move I put them back online to rebuild the mirror index. Unfortunately the power went out during the rebuild and now they show up as foreign drives.

Have I lost my data? If not, how do I bring them back up online as mirrored?